# Multiple connections from same host cause socket disconnection issues

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, tcp

I'm writting a C++ app for Linux. It uses sockets for TCP communication. I read data from remote hosts as follows (a bit simplified for this topic's needs):

```
Packet Connection::receiveRawData()
{
    int length = recv(socketDescriptor, receiveBuffer, MAXBUF, 0);
    if(length < 0)
    {
        std::cout << getConnectionDetails() << " - nothing to read.\n"; 
        return Packet(); //Empty packet object (with no data)
    }
    else if(length == 0)
    {
        std::cout << getConnectionDetails() << " - disconnected suddenly!\n";
        //Do something about this closed connection
    }

    return Packet(receiveBuffer, length);
}
```

getConnectionDetails() shows me adress and port number (like this: xx.xx.xx.xx:yy) so I would know that the message is about specific connection (since even if they're from same host they'll still have different port numbers). Couts are just for debuging purpose.

The thing is, it doesn't work quite well when I close one of the connections from the same host (ie. after making three different connection to the application, but all of them come from same machine). Only when I close them in reversed order (from newest to oldest) it works as expected - it shows "xx.xx.xx.xx:yy - disconnected suddenly!" in app's console. But when I try from oldest to newest, I keep getting "xx.xx.xx.xx:yy - nothing to read." for every connection, even though these connections should be closed!

What's going on? recv() is supposed to return 0 when remote host closed its connection, so why doesn't it happen when I close connection (from the remote host side) from oldest or even from the "middle" (neither oldest nor newest)?

It doesn't occur when I close connections from different machines (so that no machine makes more than one connection to the app) - order of these operations don't matter then, it just works fine as it should.

Edit: some more code so you can see how I set up connection sockets:

```
//Create "empty" socket object associated with the given port number
Connection::Connection(PortNumberFormat portNum)
: address(), port(portNum), socketDescriptor(socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)), isConnected(false), isListening(false), isShuttingDown(false)
{
    if(socketDescriptor < 0)
        throw std::string("Fatal error: cannot create socket! The error was: " + std::string( strerror(errno) ));
}

//Create socket object using specified socket descriptor and mark it as connected to the server
//available on specified address and port
Connection::Connection(SocketDescriptor sock, char *addr, PortNumberFormat portNum)
: address(addr), port(portNum), socketDescriptor(sock), isConnected(true), isListening(false), isShuttingDown(false)
{
    setTimeouts();
}

Connection::~Connection()
{
    if(socketDescriptor < 0) return;
    if(!isShuttingDown) signalShutdown();
    close(socketDescriptor);
}

//Turn socket into listening mode by binding it to the specified port
void Connection::startListen()
{
    if(isConnected || isListening || socketDescriptor < 0)
        throw std::string("Socket can not be set as listening!");

    struct sockaddr_in bindData;
    int dummy = 1;
    memset(&bindData, 0, sizeof(bindData));
    bindData.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bindData.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    bindData.sin_port = htons(port);
    setsockopt(socketDescriptor, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &dummy, sizeof(dummy)); //Release socket ASAP on closing
    if(bind(socketDescriptor, (struct sockaddr*)&bindData, sizeof(bindData)) < 0)
        throw std::string("Fatal error: cannot bind socket for listening! The error was: " + std::string( strerror(errno) ));
    if(listen(socketDescriptor, MAXCONN) < 0)
        throw std::string("Fatal error: cannot listen on bound socket! The error was: " + std::string( strerror(errno) ));
    isListening = true;
}

//Get new Connection object that represents external client connection
//This method will block until client connects or the socket shutdown occurs
Connection Connection::getClientConnection()
{
    if(!isListening || socketDescriptor < 0)
        throw std::string("Can't get connection from non-listening socket!");

    struct sockaddr_in clientData;
    socklen_t len = sizeof(clientData);
    SocketDescriptor clientSocket = accept(socketDescriptor, (struct sockaddr*)&clientData, &len);
    if(isShuttingDown) //An shutdown occured
    {
        if(clientSocket < 0)
            throw std::string("Information: listening connection is shutting down peacefully.");
        //Else...
        close(clientSocket); //Just to be extra sure
        throw std::string("Warning: listening connection is shutting down. Client connection has been discarded.");
    }
    if(clientSocket < 0)
        throw std::string("Fatal error: cannot open client connection socket! The error was: " + std::string( strerror(errno) ));
    return Connection(clientSocket, inet_ntoa(clientData.sin_addr), ntohs(clientData.sin_port));
}

//Invalidates socket and prepares it to be closed
void Connection::signalShutdown()
{
    if(socketDescriptor < 0) return;
    isShuttingDown = true;
    shutdown(socketDescriptor, SHUT_RDWR);
}

inline void Connection::setTimeouts()
{
    struct timeval timeout;      
    timeout.tv_sec = 2;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    if(setsockopt(socketDescriptor, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (void*)&timeout, sizeof(timeout)) < 0
        || setsockopt(socketDescriptor, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (void*)&timeout, sizeof(timeout)) < 0)
    {
        //Do something about it
    }
}

std::string Connection::getConnectionDetails()
{
    return std::string(address + ":" + std::to_string(port));
}
```

Listening connection is created using first constructor (port number only), then I call startListen() on it. Connections from hosts are returned to external code with getClientConnection() method (they are created using second constructor). Now these are our troublemakers.

Comment: Are the sockets hanging in the TIME_WAIT state? netstat -anlp can give you that information.  If so, play with the linger option on the socket.  Which side initiates the connection?  Usually if the initiating (client) side closed the connection then it close cleanly.  If seen odd ball stuff if both the client and server are on the same hosts as well, is that your case?

Comment: "Are the sockets hanging in the TIME_WAIT state?" 

Doesn't seem that way.

The connection is always initiated by the other host (application is the server here and accepts connections from remote hosts). Application is running on another machine, so that's not the case either.

Comment: It seems likely that you are mixing up info about different connections (however, that can't be determined from the small bit of code you've given).  That being said... If `recv` returns less than zero, then `errno` should be set. You should print `errno` (or better yet `strerror(errno)`) to discover what's going wrong.

Comment: @GilHamilton I don't think I'm mixing any info here, since information about disconnection itsn't shown once on the screen if I just close the oldest connection (or all of them except the newest one). What's more, after doing that and closing the newest connection, the information about all connections closed in the meantime will be shown at the same time. strerror(errno) returns "Resource temporarily unavailable" all the time (until I close newest connection which causes all of them to return 0 on recv(), eventually).

Comment: "Resource temporarily unavailable" is `EAGAIN`. I suspect therefore that you are using non-blocking mode, and that you may have a `select` or `poll` call that is being processed incorrectly, so that you end up calling `receiveRawData` on the wrong connection. Without seeing more code, there's no way to help you further.

Comment: @GilHamilton I added more code, I hope it tells you something.

Comment: I still suspect something at the next level up: I don't see you creating threads per connection so I'm assuming there's a `select` or `poll` that is being used to determine which `Connection` object's `receiveRawData` to call. (The `EAGAIN` is consistent with your use of `SO_RCVTIMEO` when used on a socket that has no data to receive -- but hasn't yet been disconnected.) You might also try "`strace -e trace=network <your program>`" to understand what is going on.

Comment: There are no selects or polls, receiveRawData() is called in loop and either returns Packet object with data or Packet object without data (if there's nothing to receive) and what the next level will do about it, it doesn't really matter. I've shown you everything regarding sockets usage in my code, there isn't anything more regarding this, really.